# How can I rewrite this block to SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SASS and I have no idea to rewrite this to SCSS syntax. It is a part of a hamburger navigation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.hamburger { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hamburger,   /* <-------
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

.hamburger::before {
  top: -8px;
}

.hamburger::after {
  top: 8px;
}
```

Should I create a mixin for this part and call it twice?

```
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 0.5626em;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
```

UPDATE:
I tried this which seems to work but not sure if I did it correctly in terms of syntax:

```
.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  &,
  &::before,
  &::after {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #0c0c0c;
    border-radius: 0.5626em;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
  }

  &::before {
    top: -8px;
  }
  
  &::after {
    top: 8px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want SASS or SCSS? Your question is a bit confusing. Also why create a mixin for that? We don't know why you call it twice..

Comment: I want the scss syntax, the one with curly braces..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  &,
  &::before,
  &::after {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #0c0c0c;
    border-radius: 0.5626em;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
  }

  &::before {
    top: -8px;
  }
  
  &::after {
    top: 8px;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's how I did it, but that larger block needs to apply to `.hamburger` as well not just `&::before, &::after`. See the original code. I put an arrow so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Adding the addition `&`, what you did in your update is fine. I added also.